# Как в vue.js передать собственный путь в vue-router

Tags: javascript, vue.js, api, vue-router

В бекенде api c сущностями - продукты , бренды и категории две последние неограниченной вложенности по методу nestedset.

сервер получает стоку например 
patch = /brand1/brand1Child2/categoryParent1/categoryParent1Child1/
парсит patch и получает продукты

```js
{ path: '/products', name: 'products',props: true, component: require('~/pages/products/main'),children: [

          {
              path: ':myPatch',
              props: true,
              component: require('~/pages/products/main')
          }
      ]},
```

Мне нужно передать patch - неограниченной  вложенности /:path/:path/:path
и вывести его

Comment: А вы уверены, что вам на фронте нужен такой путь в адресной строке?
Может все-таки query параметрами обойтись?

Comment: Здравствуйте, нужно  в адресной строке так как это будет как хлебные крошки , уже есть реализация на laravel-e.
хотел сделать spa на vue но увы я новичок в js

Comment: Думаю только регулярки. Что-то типа такого:

`const router = new VueRouter({ 
    routes: [ 
    { path: '/blog(/category/)?:category([^\/]+)?(/page/)?:page?', component: Blog } 
    ] 
});`